# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GANTracker

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime-error

Currently I am converting one older sdk based project with new SDK 9.0.

I am getting one issue what I need to consult here. If I set `"Build Active Architecture Only"` to `"YES"`, then it debugs successfully on my device iPhone 5.

[image]

But when I set it as `"No"` then it show me error at compile time. And this is showing below warning and error message.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/narendravaishnav/Naren/SVN Projects/MyApp/libGoogleAnalytics.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/narendravaishnav/Naren/SVN Projects/MyApp/libGoogleAnalytics.a (3 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GANTracker", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this some older version of `libGoogleAnalytics.a` but this work when I am debugging with my connected device and  `"Build Active Architecture Only" = "YES".`

Is there any quick suggestion for me to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the Build Active Architecture Only  option to YES, then it builds for the connected device. Since that is an iPhone 5 with an A6 (32bit) chip, then your build succeeds. If it was an iPhone 5S then it probably would not build as it has the A7 (64bit) chip.

When you set the option to NO, then it has to build for all architectures including the newer 64 bit processors.

From the error, it looks like your installation of google analytics does not include the arm64 version. Try installing the latest version. Looks like you need version 3.03 or higher.

Comment: Thanks @Rory , I have also reached the same solution as you explained. You explain this in correct wording.